# Run a .NET application from a CD with Preinstalled .NET Framework but without setup on a client PC

Tags: .net

I have built a small game in [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) that I will be distributing to users, but I don't want the application to be installed on the user's machine. The application should run from the CD only without a setup being installed on the users machine.

Assumption - .NET 2.0 will be available on all users' machines. I want my application to run only if a CD or DVD is present.

I tried [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce), but that creates a `setup.exe` file that installs the software on the user's machine.

Comment: Just distribute the .exe created when building your project.

Possible dublicate: [Best way to deploy Visual Studio application that can run without installing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946173/best-way-to-deploy-visual-studio-application-that-can-run-without-installing)

Comment: Thanks Drasive - That did work, but I am unable to get the autorun.inf to launch the exe file. I have created the autorun.inf file [Autorun] open=knowledge.exe

Comment: I posted an answer containing multiple ways to create an autorun-file.

Answer (score 1):

Just burn the EXE file on a [DVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD). Use [IMAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_Mastering_API) to check for CD/DVD presence.

Answer (score 0):

**Distribution**

Build your project with the configuration "Release".

Burn the created .exe-file (default path: "PROJECTNAME/Build/Release") and all needed files (.ddls or something) on your CD.

---

Additional Information: [Best way to deploy Visual Studio application that can run without installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946173/best-way-to-deploy-visual-studio-application-that-can-run-without-installing)

**Autorun**

Create a "autorun.inf" file on your CD and write "[autorun]" on the first line.
Chose one of the following options for the second line:

- "open" command (Windows 95 or later)

> Syntax: "open=FILENAME.exe"

*Example: "open=example.exe"*

- "shellexecute" command (Windows 2000 or later)

> Syntax: "shellexecute=FILENAME"

*Example: "shellexecute=example.exe"*

---

Source: [http://www.wizbit.net/](http://www.wizbit.net/business_card_cd_creating_autorun_file.htm)