# How to specify where C# / Visual studio saves app data

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have simple Visual Studio(VS) application which I have a settings file with. I created the settings file using VS and clicking on setting and adding in a few variables.

I plan on letting people change this setting file to fit their needs and would like to be able to tell them the directory it is located in. Currently, I have to go to my `AppData` directory and do a search for `Appname.exe.config` and it finds it in a folder like this:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\REDNZL3H.0XK\RJKNMQ3B.60H\Simp..tion_e2fd61b4844bc401_0001.0000_d3b6c2e2b08ad12c
```

This doesn't really make sense.

**How do you configure VS to save your appname.exe.config file in a decent directory / something I define ?**

Maybe something like:

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Apps\MySimpleApp\Appname.exe.config
```

---

**Update:**

After learning about the click once installer, I think this may be a better solution.
[Best Way to Deploy Visual Studio Application that can run without Installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946173/best-way-to-deploy-visual-studio-application-that-can-run-without-installing)
This allows me to just create a zip folder for a simple app, add in all the necessary files (like the settings file) and just distribute it this way. Then I can put the files wherever I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, new variables added with User scope, therefore config file located in AppData directory.
Try change variable scope to Application value.

Comment: I uninstalled program. Changed scope to application. Published then installed again. Still gives me very similar if not the same directory structure.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are using ClickOnce? It is installed to Application Cache and you cant change location.

Comment: Yes I was. Thank you. You have saved me some time looking more into this and I have decided to go another route now.