# Executable not signed at the time of publish

Tags: c#, clickonce

I am signing executable using POST build event. executable successfully signed at the time of compilation.

but when i try to publish (ClickOnce Method) its not signing project main executable.

I added Sign Manifests and its successfully sign setup.exe

Comment: this could be a possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946173/best-way-to-deploy-visual-studio-application-that-can-run-without-installing

Comment: Its not duplicate. please read my question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 using **Obj** Directory executable files to publish instead of Bin Directory.

So we need to Sign Obj directory file to publish signed executable file.