# How do I create an EXE file from Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple project in C#. It's a Windows Forms application.

I want to be able to make this into an EXE file to be able to give this out to some of my friends. I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Before you say that there is an application file in the `bin/debug` folder, yes, I know that. The thing is that I want to be able to create this into just one file where they won't be able to access the code.

Comment: If you're already aware of the executable file in the bin/Debug folder, what is the question here? Share that file to your friends and you should be done?

Comment: My problem is that if i try to copy that application file and run it the application doesnt function properly and gives an error message

Comment: @kris594 what error message? Can you try to be more specific?

Comment: It gives me an error saying an unhandled exception has occurred in my application. This is what happens when i just copy that file and paste it outside of the folder. But when i open the exe file inside the folder the application works fine

Comment: Then you're most likely relying on other files, but there is not enough information here for us to go on. If your program did not rely on surrounding file, it would work if you just copied it somewhere. Have you referenced other assemblies?

Comment: my program uses textfiles and images that are stored inside the project folder

Comment: i believe that thats where the problem may be. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Embed these files as resources]

Comment: Related (though that, like the currently single answer, also relies on the files left in the `bin` folder): *[Best way to deploy Visual Studio application that can run without installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946173)*

Answer (score 58):

Very simple steps:

1. Compile the application in **Release mode**:

- Visual Studio:
  [image]
- .NET Framework MSBuild: `msbuild.exe ConsoleApp1.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release`
- .NET Core CLI: `dotnet build -c Release` (you may need to configure the project to output EXE)

2. Open the **solution** folder
3. Open the **application project** folder
4. Open the **Bin** folder
5. Open the **Release** folder
6. Copy the **.exe** file
7. **Share it.**

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: There is no .exe file in the release folder, only pdb, dll and json.
Why wont they just makes things easy for once

Comment: @Alan Then you created a .NET Core project. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44201386/2141621)

Comment: Thanks buddy, apparently I dont have it installed.Good to know, but Ill just work around it