# Run dotnet core console app after publish

Tags: .net-core, console-application, publish

I have created .net core console app with that launchSettings.json:

```
    {
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "Built-in ConsoleApp": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://localhost:5000/"
      }
    },
    "Standalone ConsoleApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://localhost:5000/"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In Visual studio 2017 I am using "Standalone ConsoleApp" profile and console app opens.

What is proper way to publish app to other machine ?
How can I run app after publish app ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2017 missing exe file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44201334/visual-studio-2017-missing-exe-file)

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
dotnet c:\path\MyPublishedFolder\MyPublishedProject.Dll
```

If you need executable .exe, you can to add `net472` or any other net framework into your csprof

```
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.1;net472</TargetFrameworks>
```

or you need to create self contained application. Add

```
 <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

or just use

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64
```

Comment: How can I run dll or exe with launch profile set? I know that launch profile can be used with csproj, but publish package dont have csproj, only dll or exe.

Comment: launchProfile is for debugging / running application using dotnet.exe or VS. You need to concentrate on Publish Profiles. Publish Profiles also get settings from csproj