# How to export a windows forms app in c# to my desktop, as a real program?

Tags: c#, windows

I made a program in windows forms - c#, using visual studio (2017).
My question is how can i export my program from visual studio, to my desktop?

Comment: Just compile it and get the EXE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create an EXE file from Windows Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34255864/how-do-i-create-an-exe-file-from-windows-forms)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn how to deploy your windows forms application click  [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173084(v=vs.90).aspx) to have more information. This topic explains how to publish your application with clickonce or without clickonce, and how to create a setup file to deploy your applications.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `compiling` your project, not exporting it.

To do that you only have to go to the project properties,you will find it if you double-click on the project in the `Solution explorer`:

[image]

A menu will be displayed, click now on `Publish` and you will be on the `Wizard`, then you only have to follow the steps on the image.

1. Specify a path were the .exe will be located.
2. Specify the program version.
3. Publish the program.

[image]

It is not difficult to do, if you have any question just tell me.