# How can I create an exe without dlls? - C#

Tags: c#, cross-platform, exe, portability, rider

#### Introduction:

When I publish my `cs` project, many `dlls` and one `exe` is created.

When I try to run the `exe`, no problems occurred, but when I try to `copy` and `paste` the `exe` to another computer, an error occurs:

`The application to execute does not exist: 'C:\MyCSProject.dll'.`

#### Question:

How can I create just one `exe` **without** `dlls` to successfully run the `exe` on other computers?

Comment: What exact .NET version are you using? And what's the type of the main project?

Comment: I use .NET Core v3.1 and it is a console application

Comment: Probably this works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34255864/how-do-i-create-an-exe-file-from-windows-forms/34255892#34255892

Comment: That doesn't work

Comment: You may have to use this instead: `dotnet publish -p:PublishSingleFile=true`