# C# console app hangs when removed from Visual Studio directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, publishing

I'm attempting to publish a C# console application, and I'm following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16950135/1713149). However, when I copy my Debug folder in my Visual Studio project directory and paste it to my desktop, the program no longer runs. Instead, it hangs and doesn't even execute the `Console.WriteLine` command on the first line. Here is my debug folder:

[image: Debug folder]

Any clues as to what might be the problem?

Comment: If you can see the console window and nothing happens, I suppose the problem is in the source code.

Comment: The app.publish folder suggests this is a OneClick installation.  Is it?

Comment: Why not take a Release configuration instead?  That'll be stripped of any of the VS debug dependencies and tends to be more true to what's actually... well, released.

Comment: @ NineBerry As stated, though, the first line of the code is a print statement, and nothing prints.

Comment: @Robert Harvey Indeed, but it seems many have had success with this method + ClickOnce (see the link in my post)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have any anti-virus installed? I had this problem, and the root cause was that my anti-virus would always block any binary file which is being executed from a path which is not white-listed by my anti-virus (I'm using Avast). So, I had to white-list those directories where I would build my executable files. Since then, had no problem with executing the files.

Comment: I can't believe it! I've had this problem before, and I completely forgot about it. Thanks for jogging my memory! I'm using avast as well Here a quick how-to on whitelisting: http://www.getavast.net/support/managing-exceptions