# Making an installer of WPF in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: wpf

I have merged four WPF tools into one as per my client requirements. The four WPF developments was done in Visual Studio 2015, and I merged them in Visual Studio 2017, and they have given a set of instructions on how to create an EXE file using InstallShield for deployment on their machines.

But when I do it I get an error, -6416, and when I search it [here](https://flexeracommunity.force.com/customer/CCKnowledgeBase) I do not get that error code.

Long story short, how do I go about this? I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946173/best-way-to-deploy-visual-studio-application-that-can-run-without-installing), but it did not work.

Any ideas? Please note that the code is connected to the database, and I want that EXE file to work whether they have a database or not.

Comment: you need this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects

Comment: The referenced Stack Overflow is not about making an installer, but a sort of XCOPY method for running applications on other computers than the development computer.